# Screen Blinks when Screen Orientation Changes in Android?

Tags: android, orientation, android-orientation

I have two Activities `A` and `B`. I have declared the `screenOrientation` for `A` as portrait and for `B` as landscape in the manifest file. I am starting the Activity from `A` to `B`. when I am starting the Activity `A` as well as finishing the Activity `B`, My Screen is blinking. I have set that `configChanges` for both activities as `orientation` .

this is the Manifest code snippet:

```
<application
<activity android:name=".A"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustUnspecified"
            android:configChanges="orientation" />
<activity android:name=".B"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustUnspecified"
            android:configChanges="orientation" />

</application>
```

Is there any idea to resolve this issue???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: coooode... please, we need to see some code to help you better

Comment: @videre: i have edited my post... Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

First did you try to overridePendingAnimation when you are starting the intent between screens? maybe some fade or something.

also i see how this can be an issue because when you are starting a new activity there is the small bit of time untill the view is inflated in setContentView, so probably you see the screen going black until that step is complete. maybe use traceview to see where it takes up the time and maybe optimize the onCreate->onDestroy methods a bit.

Creating an activity is an expensive process. maybe if this really feels annoying to you, go with a view flipper and move all the code that you can into seperate views inflating them from xml(maybe if they arent too heavy you can load them both in onCreate and probably reuse a lot of the variables declared for the portrait view and the landscape. you will leave the dependant code in the activity and move the unique functionalities for each view into the view classes.

this is just a tought. i have done this with a coverflow and a gridView containing image thumbs and it turned out great. switching views was really fast and it had a really great low memory consumption, mainly because data was shared between the views.

**EDIT**

So you want to do something like this letting the views restart or retainConfigurationState (in the android docs it says that way orientation change is handled a bit faster).
here is the code for handling orientation change with an activity group:

I have 2 activities A and B which can be any type (TAbActivity etc... )

and i have 1 main activity called OrientationChangeActivity:

```
    public class OrientationChangeActivity extends ActivityGroup {
        private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            startChildActivity("ActivityA", new Intent(this, ActivityA.class));
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            startChildActivity("ActivityB", new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
        }
        }
............
```

This is using the link posted in my comment. I have Activity A set to orientation portrait and Activity B as Landscape. i am letting OrientationChangeActivity restart itself (doesn't contain a configChage declaration in the manifest) thus calling onCreate again and switching the activity.

You can also look at the code:

```
@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
int index = mIdList.size() - 1;

if (index < 1) {
    finish();
    return;
}

manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
mIdList.remove(index);
index--;
String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
}
```

which tells you how to create an activity inside the activityGroup and set it to the view. you can use this code to load both the activites on create here and set them according to orientation change as the content View.(meaning you need to add configChage=orientation).

Comment: I have the Activity `A` as a TabActivity Content. the Activity `B` is belongs to Activity Class. In this case, How can i work with the views. If there is no Tabhost then TabActivity should throw the Fatel Exception. Any Idea on this??

Comment: i don't really understand what you are saying. you have one TabActivity (A) that is in portrait and that one is replaced with an Activity (B) when orientation is changed?

Comment: Well i don't see how you can easily make the changes to using a single activity and a view. usually this is handled with a ActivityGroup instead of having config changes in both your activities. see this: http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html. i believe this is the best way to handle what you need and not modify your current implementations. just handle the orientation changes in the ActivityGroup and load accordingly. (i think you can load both of your activities on startup and just set the one you want as a view - according to orientation)

Comment: Have config changes there and just change the decor view to the proper activity. i think you can even wait until the next screen is loaded and then switch it (eliminating the black screen wait until setContentView() and tab initialization is finished in your child activities). The example in the link is for having multiple activities in a tab but can be easily reworked for what you need. the principle is the same.

Comment: +1. I can not get your words. Please elobarate with some code example. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please get clear about this. Activity A is a TabActivity(portrait). Activity B is an Activity(landscape).

Comment: Huge Misunderstanding between us. See I am not working for the single Activities orientation. I am having two activities. one is extending TabActivity(portrait). Another one is extending Activity(landscape). while i starting the second activity i was getting the flickering.

Comment: aaahh... try overridePendingAnimation after the startActivity(intent) and add your animation. (some fade or something like that). or improve the launch process of the second activity. if oncreate takes a long time then it will go black for a short time.

Comment: the Second Activity has a webview. I want to load a flash content in that. thats why it takes some long time to load. do you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: well loading time depends on your connection. loading flash however its a different storry... Even though android supports flash its not fast at all. actually its pretty slow because it drains the processor to run its content. everything gets slow and sluggish. Sorry i don't know of a way to optimize flash performance on android. you just have to figure out an alternative or something.